# gridview click causing postback in usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have  three user controls in one aspx page, where each user control is loading in each separate tabpanel.
Each usercontrol has gridivew and objectdatasource(which has selectmethods).
The gridview is binding data from the objectdatasource, on every postback.
I have some dropdowns, the selected values are passed to the objectdatasource on submit button click, which then populates the results in the gridview.
Now, if I click on any linkbutton on the gridview, the postback is happening and gridview is rebinding with null values, so no click event of linkbutton is happening.
Anybody can suggest me how to stop the postbacks for gridview. I tried placing the updatepanels but didnt help

Answer (score 0):

You can control the flow of the program by checking `IsPostback` in `Page_Load()` and filling the grid only when it's supposed to be filled. You can also specify your UI elements to not postback as well, if certain ones are posting back when you don't want them to. Look into the `AutoPostBack` property.

```
If (IsPostBack == true) {
    // do something, load that
}
Else {
    // do something else, don't load that
}
```

Comment: I cannot use ispostback in the pageload, it causing other controls not to postback when there is a need to post back.

Comment: @user3016064 You can use IsPostBack to only load what needs to. You don't have to load everything or not load everything because you're using IsPostBack.